# NAS set-up issue with NFS protocol in linux Mint

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, fstab, nas

I have a Synology NAS that I'm trying to map in my Linux machine as if its like a regular HDD drive. I have looked all over the internet without being able to figure out how this thing works. I have enable NFS for the shared folder `HDD_backup` in my Synology NAS, then I added this line to my `/etc/fstab` file in my PC:

```
192.168.1.5:/volume1/HDD_backup /media/my_name/Home_NAS/HDD_backup nfs nouser,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,atime,auto,rw,dev,exec,suid 0 0
```

I also tried this configuration in the `/etc/fstab` file in my PC:

```
192.168.1.5:/volume1/HDD_backup /media/my_name/Home_NAS/HDD_backup nfs user,auto,rw 0 0
```

Both these method will mount my NFS drive as root and I can't access them without sudo/root. I want to be able to map these using normal user so that all the programs can access this drive.

Can anybody suggest me the best way to map my NAS drive to my PC? Also, Is NFS the fastest/best way to map a NAS drive to a Linux PC? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, can you mount it as root, then change ownership?

Otherwise, I'm guessing it is something on the synology side.  You will need to change ownership on the synology side and unfortunately I do not know this piece of hardware.

Comment: It's fine, I know that 50 rep thing can be annoying sometimes. The answer is No, after mount i can't `chown` it. This is what I've come to after all my research, I think that there is a way to change something in the `/etc/fstab` file that should align with some uid/gid or something in the NAS server side which will allow those certain users to mount this drive without sudo/root. But, my knowledge is so fragmented that I cannot connect all these dots at this point.